# How find this such that $n\mid 3m+1$ and $ m\mid n^2+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all  pairs $(m,n)$  of positive odd integers,such that $$n\mid 3m+1$$ and $$ m\mid n^2+3$$

My idea: since 
$$3m+1=an,p\in N^{+}$$
$$n^2+3=bm$$

I fell this try is not usefull,so I can't Continue

Comment: Why is this not a convenient record of the equation? $3m+1=an$ :  $n^2+3=bm$ Such record - this can be considered a half solution.

Comment: All that I've to say is that a quick check (up to m = 300001), reveals the only valid couples (m,n) are $(1,1), (43,13)$ and $(49,37)$.

Answer (score 1):

$m$ and $n$ are odd, so $m = 2m'+1$ and $n = 2n'+1$, and really we're talking about $(2n'+1) | 3(2m' + 1) + 1 = 6m' + 5$ and $(2m' + 1) | (2n'+1)^2 + 3 = 4n'^2 + 4n' + 4 = 4(n'^2 + n' + 1)$.

Can you get farther from here?

Comment: then? how to Continue

Comment: Since $2m'+1$ is strictly odd, the factor of $4$ can be discarded...

Answer (score 0):

First manualy check which values for $n$ from $1$ to $9$ are OK.

Now, we have $$mn\mid 3mn^2+9m+n^2+3\implies mn\mid n^2+9m+3$$
so, if $n\geq 10$ we have $$mn\leq n^2+9m+3\implies m\leq {n^2+3\over n-9} $$

From $n\mid 3m+1$ we have $3m+1 = nk$, where $k$ is positive integer.
Now consider the following cases:

- If $k\geq 4$ then $${4n-1\over 3} \leq {n^2+3\over n-9} \implies n\leq ...$$
- If $k=3$ we get $3\mid 1$, impossible.
- If $k=2$ then $m={2n-1\over 3}$ so $$2n-1\mid 3n^2+9\implies 2n-1\mid 39 \implies n\in\{...\}$$
- If $k=1$ then $m={n-1\over 3}$ so $$n-1\mid 3n^2+9\implies n-1\mid 12 \implies n\in\{...\}$$